# How to make a mock patch for celery function join_native

Tags: python, mocking, celery

I make autotests for my python project that uses celery function [join_native()](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.ResultSet.join_native). How can I mock patch this function so that the callback function was returning prepared results?

Comment: This is very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple!

First, we need to create celery app with CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True.

Secondly, we need to create local celery worker, which will be to send pre-prepared results.

In third, we need to create mock patch for join_native function, which will be call our callback function.